# FCM HTTP v1 API returns 401

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to use the new HTTP v1 API of fcm but it keeps on returning a 401 error message. `message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",`. I think I supplemented the correct data when using the api getting the same error over and over. Yes I have read the documentation and other SO questions but still the same. I would just like for someone to give me a different perspective/idea what I did wrong.

Note: I am using POSTMAN to consume the API

```
POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/messages:send
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer very-long-server-key
Body:

{
   "message":{
      "token":"very-long-fcm-token",
      "data":{},
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

For reference:

[project-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha1Uo.png)

[Server Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AzjA.png)

[Rest API](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#via-rest)